# Why is my Google Sheets script not opening links from column B when I select an A column cell?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, spreadsheet

My code is running but it doesn't open the links from column B. The script is being executed but I don't know why it doesn't open the link.

It should work this way: when I click in a cell from A column it should open the cell in B column and same row.

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var numCols = range.getNumColumns();
  var urls = [];
  if (column === 1 && numCols === 1) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
      var row = range.getRow() + i - 1;
      var url = sheet.getRange(row, column + 1).getValue();
      urls.push(url);
    }
    var html = "<script>";
    for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
      html += "window.open('" + urls[i] + "', '_blank');";
    }
    html += "</script>";
    
  }
}
```

[Log Execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiNTT.png)
[Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avsqx.png)

I tried to use a onEdit trigger, but my goal is to open the link in B column when I select the A column cell equivalent row. I don't want to edit A cell to trigger this script.